# C change pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers

I'm not that familiar with C and try to add a row to a existing matrix structure with a function. This function will be used in a iteration loop.

In my code, I use the matrix `PreparedData_B4` as reference matrix. In the first step I slice 3 rows out of `PreparedData_B4` and create the matrix `ActData`. Afterwards I call the function `add_row` with the arguments `mat In`, `mat **Out` and `mat Out1`. Maybe there is also another idea to avoid the passing of the adress of `ActData (mat **Out)` and the `ActData (mat Out1)` itself. It was my only chance to get the right dimensions of `Tmp`.

EDIT: In this function, I create a temporary matrix `Temp` with the new dimensions. After `*Out = &Tmp` the new address is set and works fine in my opinion. `(**Out)->n = 3`, `(**Out)->m = 4` and `(**Out)->v[][]` is accessable.
So far, so good.

After the function is completed, things go wrong. `ActData->n = 0` and `ActData->v[][]` is not accessable.

Another questions is, how to free the memory of the "old" `ActData`?

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    #define NELEMS(x) (int)(sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
    
    // Raw data
    double raw_T7[][3] = {
     {1800, 261.753, 1032.354},
     {1750, 247.46, 1028.439},
    {1700, 250.385, 1003.689},
    {1243, 69.92, 816.569},
    {670, 67.485, 614.319},
    {533, 73.591, 533.15},
    {509, 73.404, 517.456},
    {485, 89.233, 515.994},
    {460, 110.535, 501.412},
    {435, 141.864, 471.876},
    {411, 195.009, 480.623},
    {386, 260.166, 529.444},
    {361, 375.958, 462.411}
     };
    
    // Matrix structure
    typedef struct {
        int m, n;
        double ** v;
    } mat_t, *mat;
    
    // Create new matrix
    mat mat_new(int m, int n){
    
        int i = 0;
        mat out = malloc(sizeof(mat_t));
        out->v = malloc(sizeof(double*) * m);
        out->v[0] = calloc(sizeof(double), m * n);
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) out->v[i] = out->v[0] + n * i;
        out->m = m;
        out->n = n;
        return out;
    }
    
    // Show matrix
    void mat_show(mat A){
    
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < A->m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < A->n; j++) {
                printf(" %8.3f", A->v[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    
        printf("\n");
    
    }
    
    void add_row(mat In, mat **Out, mat Out1){
        int i = 0, j = 0;
    
        // Create new matrix
        mat Tmp = mat_new(Out1->m + 1, Out1->n);
    
        for (i = 0 ; i < Tmp->n ; i++) {
            for(j = 0 ; j < Tmp->m ; j++){
                Tmp->v[j][i] = In->v[j][i];
            }
        }
    
        mat_show(Tmp);
    
        // Delete old address
        //free(Out1->v[0]);
        //free(Out1->v);
        //free(Out1);
    
        *Out = &Tmp;
    
    
    }
    
    int main()
    {
    
        int i = 0, j = 0;
    
        // Assign array address to first matrix structure
        mat PreparedData_B4 = mat_new(NELEMS(raw_T7), NELEMS(raw_T7[0]));
    
        double *ptr1[PreparedData_B4->m];
        free(PreparedData_B4->v[0]);
        free(PreparedData_B4->v);
        PreparedData_B4->v = (double **)ptr1;
    
        for (i = 0 ; i < PreparedData_B4->m ; i++) ptr1[i] = (double *)raw_T7 + i * NELEMS(raw_T7[0]);
    
        // Create new matrix with the first 3 rows of PreparedData_B4
        mat ActData = mat_new(3, PreparedData_B4->n);
    
        for (i = 0 ; i < ActData->n ; i++) {
            for(j = 0 ; j < ActData->m ; j++){
                ActData->v[j][i] = PreparedData_B4->v[j][i];
            }
        }
    
        puts("PreparedData_B4");
        mat_show(PreparedData_B4);
    
        puts("ActData");
        mat_show(ActData);
    
        puts("ActData with additional row");
        add_row(PreparedData_B4, &ActData, ActData);
        mat_show(ActData);
    
        free(PreparedData_B4);
        return 0;
    }
```

SOLUTION:
Due the solid foundation of David C. Rankin and all the other responses my working example. Many thanks!

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    #define NELEMS(x) (int)(sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
    
    // Raw data
    double raw_T7[][3] = {
     {1800, 261.753, 1032.354},
     {1750, 247.46, 1028.439},
    {1700, 250.385, 1003.689},
    {1243, 69.92, 816.569},
    {670, 67.485, 614.319},
    {533, 73.591, 533.15},
    {509, 73.404, 517.456},
    {485, 89.233, 515.994},
    {460, 110.535, 501.412},
    {435, 141.864, 471.876},
    {411, 195.009, 480.623},
    {386, 260.166, 529.444},
    {361, 375.958, 462.411}
     };
    
    // Matrix structure
    typedef struct {
        int m, n;
        double *v;
    } mat_t;
    
    // Create new matrix
    mat_t *mat_new (int m, int n)
    {
        mat_t *out = malloc (sizeof *out);          /* allocate struct */
        if (!out) {
            perror ("malloc-out");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        out->v = malloc(sizeof *out->v * m * n);    /* allocate for m * n doubles */
        if (!out->v) {
            perror ("malloc-out->v");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        out->m = m;
        out->n = n;
    
        return out;
    }
    
    // Show matrix
    void mat_show(mat_t *A)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
    
        for(i = 0; i < A->m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < A->n; j++)
                printf(" %8.3f", (A->v)[i * A->n + j]);
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    
    void add_row(mat_t *In, mat_t **Out){
    
        int i = 0, j = 0;
    
        // Create new matrix
        mat_t *Tmp = mat_new((*Out)->m + 1, (*Out)->n);
    
        for (i = 0 ; i < Tmp->m ; i++) {
            for(j = 0 ; j < Tmp->n ; j++){
                (Tmp->v)[i * Tmp->n + j] = (In->v)[i * In->n + j];
            }
        }
    
        // Delete old address
        free((*Out)->v);
        free(*Out);
    
        // Assign new address
        *Out = Tmp;
    
    
    }
    
    int main(void)
    {
    
        int rows = NELEMS(raw_T7), cols = NELEMS(raw_T7[0]);
    
        int i = 0, j = 0;
    
        // Assign array address to first matrix structure
        mat_t *PreparedData_B4 = mat_new(rows, cols); /* allocate, set m & n */
    
        /* copy raw_T7 to PreparedData_B4->v */
        memcpy (PreparedData_B4->v, raw_T7, rows * cols * sizeof PreparedData_B4->v);
    
        // Create new matrix with the first 3 rows of PreparedData_B4
        mat_t *ActData = mat_new(3, PreparedData_B4->n);
    
        for (i = 0 ; i < ActData->m ; i++) {
            for(j = 0 ; j < ActData->n ; j++){
                (ActData->v)[i * ActData->n + j] = (PreparedData_B4->v)[i * PreparedData_B4->n + j];
            }
        }
    
        puts("PreparedData_B4");
        mat_show(PreparedData_B4);
    
        puts("ActData");
        mat_show(ActData);
    
        puts("ActData with additional row");
        add_row(PreparedData_B4, &ActData);
        mat_show(ActData);
    
        free (PreparedData_B4->v);
        free (PreparedData_B4);
        return 0;
    
    }
```

Comment: Please give details on "things go wrong, I'm not able to address the pointer correctly".

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, extract a [mcve] from your code for posting here.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: You are mixing `double**` with an attempt to index a 1D array as a 2D array. There is no need for `double **` in that case. You simply need `double *v` and use a single allocation of, e.g. `out->v = calloc (sizeof *out->v, m * n)` to allocate `m * n` doubles. Then you can index `(out->v)[i * n + j]`. (don't forget to check the return of ***every*** allocation)

Comment: @Yunnosch: The function itself runs fine. After the function `ActData->n` is 0, `ActData->v[][]` is not accessable.

Comment: Please give more details. So much more that a comment is not enough and you need to [edit] your question to have enough space.

Comment: Where does `->n` become 0 and what would you expect to happen if you have 0 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can build the perfect house, you must build a solid foundation -- otherwise the house will not last.

You are confusing the use of pointers and allocated blocks of memory for storage of data. This is quite apparent in your `mat_new()` function. Think about it... You allocate for `m` pointers,

```
out->v = malloc(sizeof(double*) * m);
```

But then only use a single-pointer:

```
out->v[0] = calloc(sizeof(double), m * n);
```

(what are you using the other `m - 1` pointers for??)

You look like you want to allocate a single block of memory to store your matrix values in, but then simulate a 2D array in your indexing (which is fine and is a very efficient approach) However, to do that, you do not use a *double-pointer* for `v`, you simply use a single-pointer (e.g. `double *v;`) This provides the benefit of a single-allocation and single-free for your stored data. (you still must free the struct itself)

Let's just take your `mat_new (int m, int n)` function and get that working properly and then output the data with your `mat_show(mat_t *A)` and finally free the memory we have allocated to that point, e.g.

```
// Create new matrix
mat_t *mat_new (int m, int n)
{
    mat_t *out = malloc (sizeof *out);          /* allocate struct */
    if (!out) {
        perror ("malloc-out");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    out->v = malloc(sizeof *out->v * m * n);    /* allocate for m * n doubles */
    if (!out->v) {
        perror ("malloc-out->v");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    out->m = m;
    out->n = n;
    
    return out;
}
```

(**note:** I have removed the **typedeffed** pointer `mat`)

For your `mat_show()` function, you would then have:

```
// Show matrix
void mat_show(mat_t *A)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < A->m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < A->n; j++)
            printf(" %8.3f", (A->v)[i * A->n + j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    putchar ('\n');
}
```

(**note:** don't use `printf` to output a single-character, that is what `putchar()` is for -- though a good compiler will make that optimization for you)

If you put those functions together with a shortened example, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NELEMS(x) (int)(sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

// Raw data
double raw_T7[][3] = {  {1800, 261.753, 1032.354},
                        {1750, 247.46, 1028.439},
                        {1700, 250.385, 1003.689},
                        {1243, 69.92, 816.569},
                        {670, 67.485, 614.319},
                        {533, 73.591, 533.15},
                        {509, 73.404, 517.456},
                        {485, 89.233, 515.994},
                        {460, 110.535, 501.412},
                        {435, 141.864, 471.876},
                        {411, 195.009, 480.623},
                        {386, 260.166, 529.444},
                        {361, 375.958, 462.411} };

// Matrix structure
typedef struct {
    int m, n;
    double *v;
} mat_t;

// Create new matrix
mat_t *mat_new (int m, int n)
{
    mat_t *out = malloc (sizeof *out);          /* allocate struct */
    if (!out) {
        perror ("malloc-out");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    out->v = malloc(sizeof *out->v * m * n);    /* allocate for m * n doubles */
    if (!out->v) {
        perror ("malloc-out->v");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    out->m = m;
    out->n = n;
    
    return out;
}

// Show matrix
void mat_show(mat_t *A)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < A->m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < A->n; j++)
            printf(" %8.3f", (A->v)[i * A->n + j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    putchar ('\n');
}

int main (void)
{
    int rows = NELEMS(raw_T7), cols = NELEMS(raw_T7[0]);

    mat_t *PreparedData_B4 = mat_new(rows, cols);   /* allocate, set m & n */
    
    /* copy raw_T7 to PreparedData_B4->v */
    memcpy (PreparedData_B4->v, raw_T7, rows * cols * sizeof PreparedData_B4->v);
    
    mat_show (PreparedData_B4);                     /* output matrix */
    
    free (PreparedData_B4->v);
    free (PreparedData_B4);
}
```

(**note:** `string.h` was included to make the `memcpy()` function available to initialize `out->v` from `raw_T7` in a single call )

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/mat_prepare
 1800.000  261.753 1032.354
 1750.000  247.460 1028.439
 1700.000  250.385 1003.689
 1243.000   69.920  816.569
  670.000   67.485  614.319
  533.000   73.591  533.150
  509.000   73.404  517.456
  485.000   89.233  515.994
  460.000  110.535  501.412
  435.000  141.864  471.876
  411.000  195.009  480.623
  386.000  260.166  529.444
  361.000  375.958  462.411
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/mat_prepare
==10301== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10301== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10301== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10301== Command: ./bin/mat_prepare
==10301==
 1800.000  261.753 1032.354
 1750.000  247.460 1028.439
 1700.000  250.385 1003.689
 1243.000   69.920  816.569
  670.000   67.485  614.319
  533.000   73.591  533.150
  509.000   73.404  517.456
  485.000   89.233  515.994
  460.000  110.535  501.412
  435.000  141.864  471.876
  411.000  195.009  480.623
  386.000  260.166  529.444
  361.000  375.958  462.411

==10301==
==10301== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10301==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10301==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,352 bytes allocated
==10301==
==10301== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10301==
==10301== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10301== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This is what it appears you were trying to accomplish. Let me know if I misinterpreted your intent or if you have further questions. Get your memory use correct first to provide a solid foundation and build from there.

Comment: "(what are you using the other m - 1 pointers for??)" => `for (i = 0; i < m; i++) out->v[i] = out->v[0] + n * i;`

Comment: Okay -- I see where you are going with that. That is just another way to allow the 2D indexing -- at the cost of additional pointers and parameter complexity. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: It might be a bit less efficient due to extra pointer derefencing. But addressing via `A->v[i][j]` looks more readable than `(A->v)[i * A->n + j]);`. Anyway I just wanted to clarify that the other pointers are not unused.

Comment: I'll concede that point. I would ranter `A-v[n][j]` as well. But the benefit of the 1D indexed as 2D is to provide a single-allocation, single free, so it is somewhat a double-edge sword. Simplify the indexing, but lose the benefit of single-allocation, single-free. I guess it is a user-choice at that point.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Many thanks for your excellent answer. Adressing via `A->v[n][j]` suits me just fine.

Comment: At least it is only 2 allocations and not 1+n. Sure it is a matter of user preference.

Comment: Well -- yes, the struct itself, but for purposes of the pointer discussion I was focused on the actual `double` data handling `:)`